# How run protractor test in angular phonecat?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I try execute e2e test and get an error:

```
Failed: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'egor-home', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-32-generic', java.version: '10.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.hBVoSN}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=68.0.3440.106, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 267829a52edfd44d3eedf3d8c565e1da
```

Github issues says that error "Failed: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'" can be solved with chromedriver updating. But problem that in error message chromedriver version is 2.26.436382, while version in node_modules:

```
node_modules/chromedriver/bin$ ./chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706)
```

Is i right that root of the problem is using wrong version of chromedriver? How can i force protractor use a newest version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `angular-phonecat` git checkout gets an old version of `protractor` and its inner `webdriver_manager` (which contains the `chromedriver` being used), causing your error. Running an update on the `webdrive_manager`, `chromedriver` or `protractor` doesn't seem to grab the latest versions as their versions are managed by the `...\angular-phonecat\package.json` file. Edit the versions of the packages in this file and run `npm install`. This should remove the old versions and pull the new versions for you.

I was also running an older version of Chrome and had to update this separately as each `chromedriver` has a corresponding browser version that it is compatible with.

You can view the versions of the packages with `npm v <package> version`.

My `protractor` E2E tests passed with package versions of: `protractor` 5.4.0, `chromedriver` 2.41, `webdriver-manager` 12.1.0, alongside Chrome browser 69.0.3497.81